# Passing a glob on a script's command line, only the first item is expanded

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following directory structure and am trying to create a simple bash script to print out all files with pattern foo*/scripts/*A.txt (namely foo1/scripts/fileA.txt and foo2/scripts/fileA.txt)

```
$ tree

.
├── bar
│   └── scripts
│       ├── fileA.txt
│       └── fileB.txt
├── bash_scrap.sh
├── foo1
│   └── scripts
│       ├── fileA.txt
│       └── fileB.txt
└── foo2
    └── scripts
        ├── fileA.txt

    └── fileB.txt
```

I now create a script bash_scrap.sh where I want to print all filenames with pattern given by the first command-line argument.

```
$ cat bash_scrap.sh 
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$1 
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  printf "\n\n"
done
```

When I define FILES directly and run the script in the terminal, I get the expected output

```
$ FILES=foo*/scripts/*A.txt
$ for f in $FILES; do   echo "Processing $f file...";   printf "\n\n"; done
Processing foo1/scripts/fileA.txt file...


Processing foo2/scripts/fileA.txt file...
```

However, if I try to run this as a script with the input pattern as such, it only prints out the first filename.

```
$ ./bash_scrap.sh foo*/scripts/*A.txt
Processing foo1/scripts/fileA.txt file...
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ ./bash_scrap.sh foo*/scripts/*A.txt
```

...does not put `foo*/scripts/*A.txt` in `$1`. Instead, it *expands* `foo*/scripts/*A.txt`, and puts the first result in `$1`, the second result in `$2`, etc. This happens before your script is started (and is performed by the invoking shell, not the one than runs the script), so you can't avoid it by modifying the script's text.

If you want a glob to be passed to a script as a literal value and interpreted only after that script starts, you need to quote it:

```
$ ./bash_scrap.sh 'foo*/scripts/*A.txt'
```

---

However, a **much better** approach is to expect the parent shell to do that expansion for you, and iterate over `"$@"`:

```
for f do
  echo "Processing $f file"
done
```

This is how programs like `ls` work: When you run `ls *.txt`, the *user's shell* replaces `*.txt` with a list of matching files *before `ls` is even started*. `ls` does not expect to be given a glob, and doesn't work correctly if you *do* give it one (try running `ls '*.txt'`, and you'll see it always give a file-not-found error, unless you've created a file with that literal name).

Answer (score 0):

Updating your script as below should solve the issue. Notice $@ instead of $1, as pointed by other answer.
$0 need to be ignored from $@ and that's why IGNORE_FIRST_ARG variable is used.

```
#!/bin/bash
IGNORE_FIRST_ARG=1
for f in "$@"
do
    if [ $IGNORE_FIRST_ARG == 1 ]
    then
        IGNORE_FIRST_ARG=0
        continue
    fi  
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    printf "\n\n"
done
```

Comment: Please don't use `FILES=$@`. This mashes all of the arguments together with only spaces between them, but since spaces can occur in arguments (and filenames), you've now lost the ability to tell which spaces separate arguments and which are just part of an argument. Instead, either skip the variable and use `for f in "$@"` (or the shorthand `for f do`) directly, or store the arg list as an array: `files=("@")` (note the parentheses -- this creates an array, and will store each arg as a separate element) and then use it like `for f in "${files[@]}"`.